# Skip validation on invite rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with the devise-invitable gem and I am calling the below method but I want to skip the model validation when inviting a user.

```
if resource = User.invite!({:email => email}, current_user) do |u|
  u.skip_invitation = false
end
```

Comment: how your `invite` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
:validate_on_invite => false
```

in your model where you include all you devise modules, or maybe you could change initializers/devise.rb and set

```
config.validate_on_invite = false
```

Comment: Then definitely is because of your implementations, you need to provide broader picture